# Finding Upper Case in String Array and extracting it out

Tags: java

I have an array input like this which is an email id in reverse order along with some data:

```
MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQRqwertySDdd
MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKLasDDbfn
MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKGposDDbfn
```

I want my output to come as

```
MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQR
MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKL
MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKG
```

How should I filter the string since there is no pattern?

Comment: Use regex to filter out lower case letters.

Comment: Even if I filter all lower case letters, unwanted uppercase letters do remain which I don't want in output.

Comment: If by unwanted uppercase letters you mean any letter that comes after the first lower case, then just cut everything after the first lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern, and that is any upper case character which is followed either by another upper case letter, a period or else the `@` character.

Translated, this would become something like this:

```
String[] input = new String[]{"MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQRqwertySDdd","MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKLasDDbfn" , "MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKGposDDbfn"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z.]+@[A-Z.]+)");
    for(String string : input)
    {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
        if(matcher.find())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Yields:

```
MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQR
MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKL
MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKG
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think there is no pattern?

You clearly want to get the string till you find a lowercase letter.

You can use the regex `(^[^a-z]+)` to match it and extract.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK0iL9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simply [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) on `[a-z]`, with limit 2:

```
String s1 = "MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQRqwertySDdd";
String s2 = "MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKLasDDbfn";
String s3 = "MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKGposDDbfn";
System.out.println(s1.split("[a-z]", 2)[0]);
System.out.println(s2.split("[a-z]", 2)[0]);
System.out.println(s3.split("[a-z]", 2)[0]);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/f2qn7F).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
String arr[] = { "MOC.OOHAY@ABC.PQRqwertySDdd", "MOC.OOHAY@AB.JKLasDDbfn", "MOC.OOHAY@XZ.JKGposDDbfn" };
for (String test : arr) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*\\.[A-Z]*@[A-Z]*\\.[A-Z.]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```